# How to sort a list by date correctly?

Tags: python, sorting, date

Im trying to sort a list of data, but it seems like the sort isn't working. I first took out the date portion of the list and tried to compare it to the current date.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

test = {
    '3001265': ['Samsung', 'phone', '1200', '12/1/2023', ''],
    '1009453': ['Lenovo', 'tower', '599', '10/1/2020', ''],
    '1167234': ['Apple', 'phone', '534', '2/1/2021', ''],
    '2390112': ['Dell', 'laptop', '799', '7/2/2020', ''],
    '9034210': ['Dell', 'tower', '345', '5/27/2020', ''],
    '7346234': ['Lenovo', 'laptop', '239', '9/1/2020', 'damaged'],
    '2347800': ['Apple', 'laptop', '999', '7/3/2020', '']
}

test_dates = []
for value, index in test.items():
    if index[3] not in test_dates:
        test_dates.append(index[3])

test_day = []
today = date.today()
for date in test_dates:
    other_date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
    if other_date < today:
        other_date = other_date.strftime('X%m/X%d/%Y').replace('X0','X').replace('X','')
        test_day.append(other_date)
print(test_day)

table = range(len(test_day))
for num in table:
    entry_list = []
    for row, entry in test.items():
        entry = [row] + entry
        for line in entry:
            if test_day[num] in line:
                entry_list.append(entry)
    sorted_entry = sorted(entry_list, key=lambda x: x[4])
    for object in sorted_entry:
        print(object)
```

My goal is to find all the dates that are before today and output all thier information sorted by the date.
This is the output:

```
['1009453', 'Lenovo', 'tower', '599', '10/1/2020', '']
['2390112', 'Dell', 'laptop', '799', '7/2/2020', '']
['9034210', 'Dell', 'tower', '345', '5/27/2020', '']
['7346234', 'Lenovo', 'laptop', '239', '9/1/2020', 'damaged']
['2347800', 'Apple', 'laptop', '999', '7/3/2020', '']
```

The ideal output is with the rows ordered by the date or the 4th column:

```
['9034210', 'Dell', 'tower', '345', '5/27/2020', '']
['2390112', 'Dell', 'laptop', '799', '7/2/2020', '']
['2347800', 'Apple', 'laptop', '999', '7/3/2020', '']
['7346234', 'Lenovo', 'laptop', '239', '9/1/2020', 'damaged']
['1009453', 'Lenovo', 'tower', '599', '10/1/2020', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that the sorting was done using a string instead of a time.

Your code is too long, and it's actually very easy to do this sort.

```
from datetime import datetime

test = {
    '3001265': ['Samsung', 'phone', '1200', '12/1/2023', ''],
    '1009453': ['Lenovo', 'tower', '599', '10/1/2020', ''],
    '1167234': ['Apple', 'phone', '534', '2/1/2021', ''],
    '2390112': ['Dell', 'laptop', '799', '7/2/2020', ''],
    '9034210': ['Dell', 'tower', '345', '5/27/2020', ''],
    '7346234': ['Lenovo', 'laptop', '239', '9/1/2020', 'damaged'],
    '2347800': ['Apple', 'laptop', '999', '7/3/2020', '']
}
data = list(test.values())
result = sorted(data, key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[3], '%m/%d/%Y'))
print(result)
```

Comment: How do I compare it to today's date and only print past days this is what I have  [link](https://justpaste.it/9bgq1) But the format prints out incorrectly

Comment: try `print(entry.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))` to replace the last line.

Comment: @PythonIs2Hard `data = [x for x in test.values() if datetime.strptime(x[3], '%m/%d/%Y') < datetime.today()]`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
sorted_entry = sorted(entry_list, key=lambda x: x[4])
```

To:

```
sorted_entry = sorted(entry_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[4], '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: @Stef No it's `4`